# jQuery form submit, prevent from sending multiple times after first submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, submit, delay

I am making a webapplication that uses a jquery submit to request some data, but i don't want people submit the form multiple times after they submit the first time. So i want after a submit, that the next submit does nothing for a few seconds.

```
$("#updatestock_form").submit(function(e){

    // requesting my data..


});
```

How can i achieve this?

Comment: You can remove or disable submit button, or you can use a flag to check if a form has already been sent

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> *"So i want after a submit, that the next submit does nothing for a few seconds."*

If you mean that you want the user's second and subsequent submit attempts to be ignored until after a certain number of seconds you can do that in a number of ways. Here's the first that came to mind:

```
var allowSubmit = true;
$("#updatestock_form").submit(function(e){
    if (!allowSubmit) return false;
    allowSubmit = false;
    setTimeout(function(){ allowSubmit = true; }, 5000);

    // your existing submit code here
    // requesting my data..
});
```

That is, have a flag that indicates whether submit is currently allowed. On the submit event if that flag is false just return `false` immediately to cancel the submit event. Otherwise (if it is currently `true`) set the flag to `false`, set a timeout to change the flag back after, say, 5 seconds, and then carry on with your existing submit code.

Comment: Thank you, this is what i have been looking for!

Answer (score 2):

```
$("#updatestock_form").submit(function(e){
    $(this).unbind("submit")
    $("#submitButton").attr("disabled", "disabled")
});
```

Very simple.

Comment: and for few second thing add line for `setTimeout`

Comment: Actually this won't work, you would just remove the jQuery listener, not prevent the `form` from submitting

Answer (score 0):

You are doing an ajax-request to submit? So create some locking variable `var locked;`and set it to `locked = true;` when submitting and reset it to `false` when the ajax call is finished. (sucess-condition)

Answer (score 0):

Disable button on onclick event of button

```
$("#buttonId").bind('click', function() { $(this).attr("disabled", "disabled"); });
```

and remove disabled attribute after successful operation